# Fazer Upload Multipart usando Java SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, multipartfile

How to upload files received in the API? Using springboot java and send to a directory via http url, from cpanel for example.

I did it using aplication.properties and saved it in a local directory, but I would like to know how to save it now in a web address that has file management, in the case of cpanel.

Comment: Please check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java @RequestParam ("files") MultipartFile [] files` to receive an array of files